# Copy S3 files using the paws package

Tags: r, amazon-web-services

How could I run the following AWS CLI command using the *paws* package?

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://amazon-reviews-pds/tsv/ s3://data-science-on-aws/amazon-reviews-pds/tsv/ --exclude "*" --include "amazon_reviews_us_*"
```